# How can I get joined table values from eager loading?

Tags: json, laravel-5, eager-loading

I am working through the Laracasts video about egar loading and so far so good!

I thought I was grasping the concepts well, but now I'm hung up with how I used to do it (CodeIgniter) vs this pretty awesome way.

I have 3 tables:

```
cards        #card_id, title, created_at, updated_at
notes        #note_id, name, created_at, updated_at
card_notes   #card_id, note_id
```

Within `card_notes` there are FK fields:

```
card_id  #FK back to cards->card_id
note_id  #FK back to notes->note_id
```

I am able to get all notes for a given card:

**CardsController.php**

```
public function show(Card $card)
{
    $card->load('notes');
}
```

**Card.php**

```
public function notes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(CardNote::class);
}
```

**json**

```
{
    id: 1,
    title: "First Card",
    created_at: null,
    updated_at: null,
    notes: [
        {
            card_id: 1,
            note_id: 1,
            created_at: null,
            updated_at: null
         },
         {
            card_id: 1,
            note_id: 2,
            created_at: null,
            updated_at: null
         }
     ]            
}
```

So far, so good!
Now, within my `notes` table, I have a `name` column I want to show. This is where I am stuck. I'm able to get to my lookup table, but I haven't figured out how to get *past* that table and into the joined table. It looks like I need `hasManyThrough` but... I'm falling flat on my face.

```
return $this->hasManyThrough(Note::class, CardNote::class);
```

I need to get all note records for the given `note_id` but I'm not sure how to drill down into that next level. This is what I'm trying to generate in the end:

**json**

```
{
    id: 1,
    title: "First Card",
    created_at: null,
    updated_at: null,
    notes: [
        {
            card_id: 1,
            note_id: 1,
            name: "John Doe"
            created_at: null,
            updated_at: null
         },
         {
            card_id: 1,
            note_id: 2,
            name: "Jane Doe"
            created_at: null,
            updated_at: null
         }
     ]            
}
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it helps if you keep scrolling. I knew I was close with `hasManyThrough`, I just missed the optional params.

```
return $this->hasManyThrough(Note::class, CardNote::class, 'card_id', 'note_id');
```